# Trying to understand Socket.IO - socket and emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to understand Socket.IO, but i need help.
I'am looking at the Socket.IO docs and found this piece of code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
});
```

Source: [http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-…]):socket](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-%E2%80%A6]):socket)

Coming from an Object-oriented programming background, i understand that the first line "imports" the Socket.IO library. Furthermore it "creates an instance" of socket.io which is saved as the variable io.

But what does the the next two lines do? What is this *io.on*, what is *'connection'*, what is the origin of the *parameter socket*, and what does this mean: *some: 'data'*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But what does the the next two lines do? What is this io.on, what is
>   'connection', what is the origin of the parameter socket, and what
>   does this mean: some: 'data'?

Let's go through your code line by line and explain:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
});
```

First, the line:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
```

This line does three things.  First, it loads the module with `require('socket.io')`.  Second, it calls the constructor on the returned module with the `()` at the end.  Then, it assigns the return result from the constructor to the variable `io`.  Per the socket.io documention, calling the constructor in this way starts up a web server on the default port 80 that is listening for incoming socket.io connections.  The return result of the constructor is the socket.io server instance (in the `io` variable) that can be used for future socket.io operations.

Then, the line:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
```

The `.on()` method on the socket.io instance is a generic way of registering event handlers.  Once you get to know node.js in more detail, you will recognize this as an `EventEmitter` interface and, in fact, the socket.io instance is a subclass of `EventEmitter`.  So, with this particular `.on()` method call, you are registering an event handler for the `'connection'` event.

Socket.io will call the connection event any time a new socket.io connection is established with your socket.io server.  This is your way of getting notified any time a new client connects.  Per the socket.io documentation, the callback you pass for that event will be passed one argument which is the `socket` object associated with the newly established connection.  This event handler allows you to see each new socket.io connection right when they are first connected.

Then, the line:

```
socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
```

This says that when a new connection is established, you want to immediately send that new `socket` a message.  In socket.io a message consists of two parts - first, the message name and second some optional message data.  In this particular case, the message name is `'an event'`.  Message names must be a string, but you can make them pretty much any string name you want (I think there may be a few reserved names such as ping and pong, but other than that, this is entirely up to you to make up a message name.  In order to receive a message that you server sends , the client on the other end of the connection will just need to listen for the exact same message name that you send here.

The second argument to `.emit()` is optional and can be some data that you want to send with the message.  Here's a simpler example to illustrate:

```
socket.emit('setColor', 'blue');
```

This sends the `'setColor'` message and sends the data `"blue"` with it so that the receiving client knows what color it should be set to.

The data can be any Javascript data that can be properly represented in JSON.  Because you can't actually send live Javascript objects or arrays over a network, those objects are serialized into the JSON format and then sent as text.  The receiving client will deserialize it and turn it back into whatever data type it was supposed to be.  So, in your specific example, it was doing this:

```
socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
```

That was sending a Javascript object.  The `{ some: 'data' }` syntax in Javscript is the declaration of an object literal.  In this particular case, this is a Javascript object that has one property with the name `some` and the value of that property is `'data'`.  This is obviously just for example purposes as a real application would likely have more meaningful data such as:

```
socket.emit('format', {fontSize: 16, color: 'blue', type: 'san serif'});
```

Then, the receiving client would get a Javascript object with all three properties on it `fontSize`, `color` and `type`.

Then, the line:

```
});
```

This just closes off the `io.on(...` line that was started before.

Answer (score 0):

`io.on('connection'...` basically tells Socket.io to listen on this event. When socket.io establishes a connection, we execute the callback:

```
 function (socket) { ... }
```

The next line:

```
 socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
```

tells socket.io to emit, or send an event through the pipeline with the name `an event` as well as the data `{ some: 'data' }`. If you understand how events work in jQuery or regular old js, then this flow would be familiar. Here's an example in jQuery

```
 // listening for the click event
 $('.foo').click(function (e, data) { // data is equal to foo
      alert('clicked');
      return false;
 }
```

and for triggering (emitting)

```
 $('a').trigger('click', [ 'foo' ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, i'm not familiar with jQuery. 
I still don't understand what this means: "some: 'data' ". I don't understand this syntax, and what is exactly happening.

Comment: @qwerty - it sounds like you need to back up and learn/study some Javascript basics.  `{some: 'data'}` is a Javascript object literal definition.  `some` is a property name.  `'data'` represents some meaningful data (this is just a placeholder in the demo) that is the value of that property.  This object is serialized and sent to the other end of the new socket.io connection where the client can receive an object that looks just like this one